# How to extract a list of items from string in SQL

Tags: mysql, json

I want to split itemid into a list as I want to use the list as a condition in another query:

```
data
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[{"shopid":64522541,"itemid":1260324852},{"shopid":31863766,"itemid":1265550228}]
```

I have tried JSON_EXTRACT like this:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(data,'$.itemid') from table
WHERE collection_id = 88888
```

but it's not working. Can you please help a way to extract a list that I can use in the below code:

```
Select id in table2 
where id in LIST
```

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: In Postgres you can use `json_array_elements()` to turn the array into rows.

Comment: In oracle 12c you can use `json_value` function to extract element you desire

Comment: Top hit when googling "sql JSON_EXTRACT" is MySql.

Answer (score 0):

for postgrey below query may help

```
  select  (d->>'itemid')::numeric itemid
        from 
         json_array_elements(data::json) d
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query to fetch list of itemids:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(data,'$[*].itemid') from table WHERE collection_id = 88888;
```